# Is there any way to reuse the same devise invitation_token on resend invitation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-invitable

When someone is invited to manage multiple users, with every new invitation, the token is changed and it is invalidating previous invitations.

It should not change the token but try to reuse it. If it is not possible, then is there any way to allow the user to use any of them until the user is signed up?

Comment: This is way beyond the scope of what devise invitable is designed to do. Can you modify it to do this? Yeah maybe. But you would probably be better off writing something purpose built as it going to be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Try tweaking `File 'lib/devise_invitable/models.rb', line 139` to get your desirable result..